# Prestashop Multistore Domain Aliases

Tags: prestashop, multistore

I am trying to setup a multistore environment using multiple domainnames. So I have multiple shops, that are controlled by one backend. However, I have pointed my domain DomainB.com to DomainA.com in DirectAdmin, this works, however, it goes to my shop on DomainA.com, and not to the second store I created in Prestashop, that should be DomainB.com. How do I configure this correctly? The Prestashop documentation confuses me.